# Creating arbitrary concave shapes in XNA/WP7 using sprites/polygons?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geometry, xna, shapes

What's the best way to draw arbitrary textured shapes in WP7/XNA? I'm thinking I'm going to have to use polygons in orthographic projection but if there is a method to do this using textures I would much prefer that.

Comment: When you say "using textures", do you mean "using sprites"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is with textured polygons in an orthographic projection :)

You could pre-compute textures for sprites in the shapes you want - but that has its own problems. The first two I can think of are: 1) having to implement it! and 2) burning through a whole lot of texture-fetch, fill-rate and texture memory to draw a lot of blank space.

Comment: I thought as much, the only way I could think of using textures/sprites would be as you mentioned and that is needlessly complicated and painful..